# Why is NTP Clock not syncing with NTP Server in another continent?

Tags: 16.04, ntp

My Ubuntu `16.04.5 PC` is located in `Delhi, India`.

I am trying to sync my system clock with USA NTP Server.
In my system's `/etc/ntp.conf` file, I have used the following configuration:

```
# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.
# pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
# pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
# pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
# pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org
server 3.us.pool.ntp.org

# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
# pool ntp.ubuntu.com
```

The output of `ntpq -p` is:

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*hydrogen.consta 209.51.161.238   2 u   46   64  377  223.270  -93.650  47.200
+horp-bsd01.horp 152.2.133.54     2 u   47   64  377  271.806  -103.56  35.670
 ntpool1.603.new .XFAC.          16 u 1463  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
+69.10.161.7     195.205.216.85   3 u   30   64  377  268.569  -95.798  54.450
```

But my system is still in Indian Standard Time (IST). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The NTP servers you use have nothing to do with your time zone.

Comment: There is just one universal time that is provided by every time server. IST is just the way it is displayed on your local machine.

Comment: @Jos, So whichever NTP Server I may put in the conf file, the system will always show the time in my timezone? Its located in /etc/timezone (Asia/Kolkata)

Comment: Yes. You can change your time zone from Settings - Details - Date and time.

Comment: fyi:  Check your system is up-to-date; 16.04.6 was released 1-March-2019, so your system should report 16.04.6 as its current release (unless you were providing what you installed, not your current system state).

Comment: @guiverc, Thanks but the company is using docker in the server where I will later configure the NTP and the ubuntu version needs to be 16.04.5. we can't upgrade the OS or many services start failing. This is why my PC is also on the same version.

Comment: @AnujKalra That sounds like a *very* broken setup. If upgrading packages, while staying on the same LTS release breaks things, you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTP *always* distributes time in UTC. It does not matter where it's located.

Time zones are applied at your computer, and different users can have different time zones. Internally, Unix keeps track of time in UTC.

To change time zone, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

You can also change the timezone for a single command:

```
[~]$ TZ=UTC; date
Fri 17 May 07:34:05 UTC 2019
[~]$ TZ=CEST; date
Fri 17 May 07:34:07 CEST 2019
[~]$ TZ=EST; date
Fri 17 May 02:35:03 EST 2019
[~]$
```

Here I first show UTC time, then Central European Summertime (my local TZ), and then Eastern Standard Time, which is used in the eastern part of the United States.

When you select NTP servers, select **local** servers. This probably means indian servers. You want as low latency and low jitter as possible. This probably means you should use `in.pool.ntp.org`, unless you have special requirements.

Comment: The wifi devices that I am going to install is going to be in a different timezone.
I want my AWS EC2 machine to be in sync with the Wi-Fi Device to ensure seamless communication between the two systems. The region of my AWS system is Mumbai (timezone Asia/Kolkata). This is why I want to sync my EC2 server with the same NTP from which my Wi-Fi device will take time.

Comment: Time zone does not matter for NTP synchronization. Time zone is simply added to the time before it's displayed. For the time to be accurate and precise you want to use local NTP servers. You should care about UTC time being in sync, and not care about time zone. Time zones are for the convenience of humans. For computer communication, stick with UTC.

Comment: In addition, time synchronized to within a second is generally enough for most general computing purposes. Within one second is ***trivially*** achievable by NTP. You may have special requirements requiring more accurate time, but in that case you should spend some time on designing synchronization.